# MySQL Workbench won't work with Google Cloud SQL Proxy

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm using Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation and installed [cloud-sql-proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy) on my local machine.

On my local machine I'd simply connect to 127.0.0.1:3306 and this has been working fine, in NodeJs, Php and using the mysql command line client.

On Google App Engine Managed VM (flexible environment) i'm using unix_socket or socketPath '/cloudsql/MY_PROJECT_ID:us-central1:SQL_INSTANCE' this has been working fine too, in both, Php and NodeJs.

What doesn't work is MySQL Workbench, I can't figure out how to get it to connect. Does it use another protocol or is cloud-sql-proxy for command line only ?

Here is how I start cloud-sql-proxy

this works:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=MY_PROJECT:us-central1:MY_SQL_INSTANCE=tcp:3306 \
  -credential_file='/Users/ME/SomeFolder/MY_SERVICE_ACC_KEY.json'
```

after that I'd use MySQL Workbench to try to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306, but I always get an error :

```
SSL connection error: socket layer receive error
```

local PHP, NodeJS and mysql client work though.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I got it working and believe it might be useful for others too:

I couldn't get it working over the tcp connection, but I figured out how to use the socket method running without fuse:

```
sudo  ./cloud_sql_proxy \
  -dir=/cloudsql \
  -instances=MY_PROJECT:MY_SQL_REGION:MY_SQL_INSTANCE \
  -credential_file='/Users/ME/some_folder/MY_SERVICE_ACC_KEY.json'
```

couple of things here:

1. The folder `/cloudsql` has to already exists e.g. `sudo mkdir /cloudsql`
2. Don't mistype that folder name, really don't
3. Don't specify the tcp port after `instances` or it will use a tcp connection instead.
4. sudo is necessary

In MySQL Workbench:

1. Select `Database > Manage Connections...`
2. Under `Connection > Connection Method` choose `Standard (TCP/IP)`
3. Under `Parameters` set `Host: localhost` `Port:3306` (although I don't think it matters)
4. Goto `Advanced` > `Others:` enter `socket=/cloudsql/MY_PROJECT:MY_SQL_REGION:MY_SQL_INSTANCE`
5. Click `Test Connection` it should as for your username and password, success.

Comment: ... but I'd still be interested to know why it won't work over TCP/IP

Comment: But it works over TCP/P. Your step 2 in WB indicates that. o_O

Comment: @MikeLischke I assume the socket option from step 4 overrides that, as i can put anything into host and it still works. Check the comments under Vadims thread, it's a MySQL Workbench bug.

Comment: Note: sudo is only needed if the user running the "cloud_sql_proxy" does not have permissions to read/write files in the "/cloudsql" directory.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that MySQL Workbench is requesting an SSL connection, which is not supported via the proxy. The proxy always uses SSL between the local machine and the instance so there's no need to enable SSL at the MySQL protocol level.

Can you try turning off SSL in MySQL Workbench connection settings?

Comment: I did that yesterday in a act of desperation, but I gave it another try and changed from 'If available' to 'Never', still the same error. Any other place where I should disable SSL ?

Comment: It's possible you are hitting this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74896. What OS are you running this on?

Comment: OS X 10.11.4, I looked through the bug report and this might be really it.

Comment: We're looking into how we can improve the SSL handling in the proxy connectivity to handle this issue. We have some ideas on what we can do to prevent this from happening. For now you may have to stick to unix sockets.

Comment: Confirmed, it's a Workbench (6.3.6 build 511 CE 64bit OS X) bug, it simply won't honour the SSL settings no matter what. it is working fine on 6.2.5.0 build 397 32bit OS X.

Comment: thanks for the help, i'll add it to the bug report you mentioned earlier. I don't see that as a Cloud-SQL-Proxy issue, as it is working fine with all the other tools. Just one thing, it took me a while to figure out the options with `cloud_sql_proxy`, partly because if used with `dir=...instances...=tcp:3306` it would still print out `Socket Prefix: /cloudsql` which is confusing, because it isn't really using sockets.

Comment: just one more thing, I also used my local MySQL installation, to which it also connects without SSL and this works. It seems like Workbench will always give it a try, as if stuck in 'If available' mode. But the local MySQL installation seems to report back properly that SSL is not available, maybe that's a thing cloud_sql_proxy could also handle ?

Comment: Yes, that's one thing we are looking at (modifying the server handshake message to not report SSL support).